# Взаимодействие с другими окнами. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Решил написать что-то вроде punto switcher'a, и возник вопрос – а как python может считывать что-либо из посторонних окон, к примеру, браузера?
Начал реализовывать вариант с перехватом нажатий клавиш, хранением дубликата текста, и после обработки, отправки "правильных" нажатий (до последнего пункта пока не дошёл), но понял, что он не очень хороший. Могу ли я как-то взаимодействовать с другими окнами напрямую?

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно погуглить "Hook global keyboard events on Windows". Самое простое - использовать https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: Да, именно так и начал реализовывать вариант с перехватом нажатий, но насколько он правильный? Думал, более корректно было бы взаимодействовать именно с окном, о чём, собственно, и вопрос. Ведь если потом имитировать нажатия клавиш, а не передавать исправленный текст в поле, то в каких-то окнах это может вызвать лишние хоткеи, особенно с учётом того, что такой вариант никак не может проверить, вводится ли текст в какое-либо текстовое поле, или это "не текстовые" нажатия.

Comment: Я более правильного не представляю. Тебе придётся определять, где находится фокус и "текстовость" этого hWnd. Не уверен, что это возможно. скорее вайтлист приложений, где твоё приложение будет автоматически активно. Можно ведь и ручной режим оставить. Как опцию.